# comparison between 2 vectors (equal (vector 2 3 4) (vector 2 3 4)) = NIL

Tags: common-lisp

in common lisp, we have:

```
(equal (vector 2 3 4) (vector 2 3 4)) = NIL
(equal (cons 1 2) (cons 1 2)) => T
```

Why first one is false and second is true?

Comment: This might help: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2004/08/08/equality-in-lisp/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Common Lisp [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equal.htm):

> For *conses*, **equal** is defined recursively as the two *cars* being **equal** and the two *cdrs* being **equal**.
>
> Two *arrays* are **equal** only if they are **eq**, with one exception: *strings* and *bit vectors* are compared element-by-element (using **eql**).

`vector` creates an array, but it's not a string or bit vector. Since the two arrays are not `eq`, they aren't `equal`.

If you want a comparison predicate that treats arrays as equivalent if they have all the same elements, use [`equalp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equalp.htm)